# A C# method on using static functions

Tags: c#, static, delegation

I am writing C# applications that use an SDK, called PQLabs SDK.

In the sample code, the functions are set to delegate:

```
static PQMTClientImport.PFuncOnReceiveGesture cur_rg_func = new PQMTClientImport.PFuncOnReceiveGesture(OnReceiveGesture);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void PFuncOnReceiveGesture()

static void OnReceiveGesture(ref PQMTClientImport.TouchGesture gesture, IntPtr call_back_object)
```

In the function OnReceiveGesture, I want to call and use the variable of a form. But inside the function it cannot call the variable or functions inside.

Is there a way to use them?

I have checked some solutions online: [Call non-static method from static method c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716450/call-non-static-method-from-static-method-c-sharp)

But since I want to use those non-static variables in the form so it seems it is not a possible solution.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you send an event? Then you could recieve the event in a non-static method.

Comment: Hard to say without some further insight into you architecture, but why make both static?

Comment: Make OnReceiveGesture non-static and instantiate cur_rg_func once your instance is created ?

Comment: it seems not possible, the SDK provides PFuncOnReceiveGesture which is static and the related functions can't be non-static.

>Christian, when the gesture is received, it will call the PFuncOnReceiveGesture, I think there is no way to send event.

Comment: YOu could define your own event - which is then sent.