# How to call a non static method from static method

Tags: c#, asp.net, static

I need to call a non static method from a `static[webmethod]`. It is not getting call, I tested it using breakpoints.i tried to call it by making a instance to the class.
This is what i am trying .

```
[WebMethod]
public static string get_runtime_values(string get_ajax_answer_title,string get_ajax_answer_des)
{
     if (get_ajax_answer_title.Equals("") && (get_ajax_answer_title.Equals("")))
     {
        return "null";
     }
     else
     {
        int got_question_id = getting_question_id;
        DataHandler.breg obj = new DataHandler.breg();
        obj.add_anwers(got_question_id, get_ajax_answer_title, get_ajax_answer_des);
        return "inserted";
     }

     querystring object_new = new querystring();
     object_new.show();
  }
```

querystring is name of the class here.The control is going into if and else statements depending upon input,but after that it directly get jump out.Moreover when i hover the mouse over querystring ,it says

```
Unreachable code detected.
```

What should I do to make it working?

Comment: You have a `return` in both the `if` and `else` sections... you'll never reach the next line

Comment: also: replace `if (get_ajax_answer_title.Equals("") && (get_ajax_answer_title.Equals("")))` with `if (get_ajax_answer_title.Equals("") && (get_ajax_answer_des.Equals("")))`

Comment: You could have googled this before posting such question it will save every ones time at SO.this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360183/call-non-static-method-from-static-method-c-sharp.

Comment: @ankur That won't help, the cause is completely different.

Comment: @hvd oops i didn't check the complete stuff yup freefaller has pointed out the thing which needs to be changed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  [WebMethod]
public static string get_runtime_values(string get_ajax_answer_title,string get_ajax_answer_des)
    {  string result;
       if (get_ajax_answer_title.Equals("") && (get_ajax_answer_title.Equals("")))
        {
            result="null";
        }
        else
        {
            int got_question_id = getting_question_id;
            DataHandler.breg obj = new DataHandler.breg();
            obj.add_anwers(got_question_id, get_ajax_answer_title, get_ajax_answer_des);
            result="inserted";
       }
        querystring object_new = new querystring();
        object_new.show();
return result;
       }
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to just put code... for one thing, it's not always obvious what your change is, and it's always better to give a reason for the change

Answer (score 2):

That's because you `return` from both halves if the preceding `if` statement.

There is no way for it to get up to that line.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a return statement in both the IF and ELSE section.

So regardless of the result of the conditional; you never get below that.

Answer (score 1):

Your method ends after the if statement, wether it is true (`return "null"`) or not (`return "inserted"`). So your code that is after the if statement (where you create the query string) can never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are exiting your method in both your if and else clauses. Your code is essentially:

```
MyMethod() 
{
    if (someCondition)
        return
    else
        return

    // Any code at this point cannot be executed, because 
    // you have definitely returned from your method.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
querystring object_new = new querystring();
object_new.show();
```

part will never be reached because in both of your block statement in your condition you wrote a return.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is because you have return statements at the end of both your if and else blocks.

Change it to

```
[WebMethod] 
public static string get_runtime_values(string get_ajax_answer_title,string get_ajax_answer_des) 
{ 
string ret = "null";
 if (!get_ajax_answer_title.Equals("") || (!get_ajax_answer_title.Equals(""))) 
 { 
    int got_question_id = getting_question_id; 
    DataHandler.breg obj = new DataHandler.breg(); 
    obj.add_anwers(got_question_id, get_ajax_answer_title, get_ajax_answer_des); 
    ret = "inserted"; 
 } 

 querystring object_new = new querystring(); 
 object_new.show(); 

return ret;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`Unreachable code detected.` is because both paths of your if statement return early.

```
    if (get_ajax_answer_title.Equals("") && (get_ajax_answer_title.Equals("")))
    {
        return "null"
    }
    else
    {
        return "inserted";
   }
   // Can't get here.
```

You have answered your original question correctly, i.e. Instantiate an instance of a non-static method to be able to call a method on it.

```
querystring object_new = new querystring();
object_new.show();
```