# Calling Page Methods

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, jquery

I am using ajax call back for void method.But if i call other method in the calling method.M geeting error.Any help me would be appericiated.
Below is my code

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void BindNextActions()
    {
        BindGridView(); ---Error at this point..its a private void method


    }
```

Comment: Is `BindGridView()` an event method?

Comment: hi viki ,its a private void method

Comment: hi viki, m getting this errorError 103 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call a non-static function from a static function. This is the reason for the error. The solution can be found in the following link.
[How do I call a non-static method from a static method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360183/how-do-i-call-a-non-static-method-from-a-static-method-in-c)