# How can I use a method's (whose argument has been passed by ref) return value in Main()

Tags: c#

I have the following C# code:

```
public class Test 
{ 
    public string Docs(ref Innovator inn) ///Innovator is an Object defined in the   framework of the application
    {  
        //// some code 
        string file_name = "filename";
        return file_name;
    }  

    public static void Main ()/// here I' m trying to use the above method' s return value inside main()
    {
         Test t = new Test();
         string file_name1 = t.Docs(ref inn); 
    }
}
```

This sample code is throwing some errors.

1. 'inn' does' t exists in the current context,
2. method has some invalid arguments.

Why is this?

Comment: You must allocate an Innovator and pass the Reference to the Docs Method.

public static void Main ()  {
          Test t = new Test();

   Innovator inn = new Innovator(); // or get an Innovator somewhere

          string file_name1 = t.Docs(ref inn); 
}

Answer (score 3):

> 1: 'inn' does' t exists in the current context,

You haven't defined `inn` anywhere in your code. It should be like:

```
Test t = new Test();
Innovater inn = new Innovator(); //declare and (instantiate)
string file_name1 = t.Docs(ref inn);
```

Or You can get the `inn` from the framework something like:

```
Innovater inn = GetInnovaterFromTheFramework();
```

Where your method `GetInnovaterFromTheFramework` would return you the object from the framework.

The way you are passing the argument to the parameter with `ref` keyword is right, the only thing is that `inn` doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but there is a problem. I can' t call Innovator constructor in c# it is allowed only in Javascript.  This is respective to the application.

Comment: second, I can use Innovator inn = this.getInnovator() . But inside Main() 'this' is not allowed. Is' t it?

Comment: ummm What ?? how do you have class `Innovater` then ?

Comment: You can't use `this` inside a static method,

Comment: I have been calling it using 'this'. This is for first time I' m trying to call from method.

Comment: @user2314238, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360183/how-do-i-call-a-non-static-method-from-a-static-method-in-c

Comment: @user2314238, just try `new Test().getInnovator();` in your Main

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare an Innovator instance in main():

`Innovator inn = new Innovator();`