# non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context error when creating a new object instance

Tags: object, static, instance-variables

I am trying to create a new object of teacher and student but it is giving me an error. It stops giving me the error if I remove static from main but then it can't find main to run. I really do not understand why it is giving me this error. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class Person
{
   String personName = "";
   String personAddress = "";

   public Person(String name, String address)
   {
      personName = name;
      personAddress = address;
   }

   class Student 
   {
      int numCourses = 0;
      String[] courses = new String[10];
      int[] grades = new int[10];
      
      Student(String name, String address)
      {
         personName = name;
         personAddress = address;
      }
      
   }
   
   class Teacher 
   {
      int numCourses = 0;
      String[] courses = new String[20];
      
      public Teacher(String name, String address)
      {
         personName = name;
         personAddress = address;
      }
      
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Student student1 = new Student("Aaron", "1234 this road S"); //error pointing at new

      Teacher teacher1 = new Teacher("Fatima", "1111 some road N"); //error pointing at new
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple things going on here, so I'll start at the beginning, although this might be show your question to be "too broad" for this site. Your code looks like C#, so I'll use that language for example code, but it should work similarly in Java and other similar OO languages.

First of all, `main` needs to be static for the compiler to pick it up and run the program, and so does the `class` it resides in. Let's move that around some.

```
internal static class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      Student student1 = new Student("Aaron", "1234 this road S");

      Teacher teacher1 = new Teacher("Fatima", "1111 some road N");
   }
}
```

I gave this class a generic name, since we need the "Person" class name or the next bit.

Normally, you want to have classes in their own files. This is a [code styling](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/why-coding-style-matters/) thing. It's not a hard rule, but it's a very, extremely, strong recommendation among the places I've worked (and I have 10 years professional experience). So lets create a new file.*

```
public class Person
{
   string personName;
   string personAddress;

   public Person(String name, String address)
   {
      personName = name;
      personAddress = address;
   }
}
```

Now we don't *need* [inheritance](https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/inheritance), but it makes things easier. So here's a couple new files.

```
class Student : Person
{
   int numCourses = 0;
   string[] courses = new String[10];
   int[] grades = new int[10];

   public Student (string name, string address): base (name, address)
   {}
}
```

and

```
class Teacher : Person
{
   int numCourses = 0;
   string[] courses = new String[20];

   public Teacher(string name, string address): base (name, address)
   {}
}
```

And just like "magic", it works. So why?

Well, like I said, the compiler needs the `Main` method to run the program, so that has to be static. And, so the compiler knows where to at least attempt to look for `Main`, the class containing it needs to be static, too.

Static methods can't call non-static methods or variables directly. You have to create an instance of the method in order to call the method. That is done by creating a new, non-static class that contains the non-static method.
[How do I call a non-static method from a static method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360183/how-do-i-call-a-non-static-method-from-a-static-method-in-c)

[This article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-call-nonstatic-method-from-static-method) describes it a little bit, but it's generally frowned on to create an instance of a class within that instance of the class.

With inheritance, you can create one class like you did with `Person`, then use it as a basis for other classes, like you were trying with `Student` and `Teacher`, you just had it inside out, sort of. With using the `base` keyword in your individual constructors, you are calling the base constructor with the needed variables.

Another style guide is that you don't need to assign a default value to a variable or property when you are going to assign a real value to it in your constructor.

<sub>*Yes, this small of a program will work with it all being in one file, but when/if this grows larger, it'll become unmanageable. Also, your (future) co-workers may/will dislike you for cramming everything into a single file. Coding styles change over time and by team, so YMMV.</sub>